# Extract column from data.frame faster than from matrix - why?

Tags: r, performance, dataframe, matrix, subset

I'm running a simulation where I need to repeatedly extract 1 column from a matrix and check each of its values against some condition (e.g. < 10). However, doing so with a matrix is 3 times slower than doing the same thing with a data.frame. Why is this the case?

I'd like to to use matrixes to store the simulation data because they are faster for some other operations (e.g. updating columns by adding/subtracting values). How can I extract columns / subset a matrix in a faster way?

#### Extract column from data.frame vs matrix:

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:1e4)
m <- as.matrix(df)

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  df$a, 
  m[ , "a"])

# Results; Unit: microseconds
#      expr    min      lq     mean median      uq     max neval cld
#      df$a  5.463  5.8315  8.03997  6.612  8.0275  57.637   100   a 
# m[ , "a"] 64.699 66.6265 72.43631 73.759 75.5595 117.922   100   b
```

#### Extract single value from data.frame vs matrix:

```
microbenchmark(
  df[1, 1],
  df$a[1],
  m[1, 1], 
  m[ , "a"][1])  

# Results; Unit: nanoseconds
#         expr   min      lq     mean  median      uq    max neval  cld
#     df[1, 1]  8248  8753.0 10198.56  9818.5 10689.5  48159   100    c 
#      df$a[1]  4072  4416.0  5247.67  5057.5  5754.5  17993   100    b  
#      m[1, 1]   517   708.5   828.04   810.0   920.5   2732   100    a   
# m[ , "a"][1] 45745 47884.0 51861.90 49100.5 54831.5 105323   100    d
```

I expected the matrix column extraction to be faster, but it was slower. However, extracting a single value from a matrix (i.e. `m[1, 1]`) was faster than both of the ways of doing so with a data.frame. I'm lost as to why this is.

#### Extract row vs column, data.frame vs matrix:

The above is only true for selecting columns. When selecting rows, matrices are much faster than data.frames. Still don't know why.

```
microbenchmark(
  df[1, ],
  m[1, ],
  df[ , 1],
  m[ , 1])

# Result: Unit: nanoseconds
#     expr   min      lq     mean  median      uq   max neval  cld
#  df[1, ] 16359 17243.5 18766.93 17860.5 19849.5 42973   100    c 
#   m[1, ]   718   999.5  1175.95  1181.0  1327.0  3595   100    a   
# df[ , 1]  7664  8687.5  9888.57  9301.0 10535.5 42312   100    b  
#  m[ , 1] 64874 66218.5 72074.93 73717.5 74084.5 97827   100    d
```

Comment: Note that `m[1,"a"]` is faster than subsetting a df.

Comment: it's an interesting theoretical question ... but is extracting columns actually a bottleneck in your simulation code?  (extracting a single column of a matrix takes on average 72,000 *nanoseconds* ... you may be doing this millions of times, but is it the slowest thing you're doing?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### data.frame

Consider the builtin data frame `BOD`.  data frames are stored as a list of columns and the `inspect` output shown below shows the address of each of the two columns of `BOD`. We then assign its second column to `BOD2`. Note that the address of `BOD2` is the same memory location as the second column shown in the `inspect` output for `BOD`.  That is, all R did was have `BOD2` point to memory within `BOD` in order to create `BOD2`.  There was no data movement at all.   Another way to see this is to compare the size of `BOD`, `BOD2` and both together and we see that both together take up the same amount of memory as `BOD` so there must have been no copying.  (Continued after code.)

```
library(pryr)

BOD2 <- BOD[[2]]
inspect(BOD)
## <VECSXP 0x507c278>
##   <REALSXP 0x4f81f48>
##   <REALSXP 0x4f81ed8>  <--- compare this address to address shown below
## ...snip...

BOD2 <- BOD[,2]
address(BOD2)
## [1] "0x4f81ed8"

object_size(BOD)
## 1.18 kB
object_size(BOD2)
## 96 B
object_size(BOD, BOD2)    # same as object_size(BOD) above
## 1.18 kB
```

### matrix

Matrices are stored as one long vector with dimensions rather than as a list of columns so the strategy for extraction of a column is different.  If we look at the memory used by a matrix `m`, an extracted column `m2` and both together we see below that both together use the sum of the memories of the individual objects showing that there was data copying.

```
set.seed(123)

n <- 10000L
m <- matrix(rnorm(2*n), n, 2)
m2 <- m[, 2]

object_size(m)
## 160 kB
object_size(m2)
## 80 kB
object_size(m, m2) 
## 240 kB  <-- unlike for data.frames this equals sum of above
```

### what to do

If your program is such that it uses column extraction up to a point only you could use a data frame for that portion and then do a one time conversion to matrix and process it like that for the rest.

Comment: +1 Starting with DF and moving to matrix won't speed things up in my case, because I would need to repeatedly convert each, which takes up as much time as the time saved by using a DF.  I will try splitting up the matrix into vectors and performing operations on each individual vector. Thanks for the informative response.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it is about the data structure of R in the memory.
A matrix in R is a 2-d array, which is the same of 1-d array. A variable is a point directly to the memory, so it would be very faster to extract a single value. To extract a column in the matrix, it would take some computation and ask for new memory address and save it. As for dataframe, it is actually a list of columns, so it would be faster to return a column.
That's what i guess, hope to be proved.

Comment: You could add *As for dataframe, it is a actually a list of columns **that can be of different classes***.